# Invoking parent functors in Julia

Tags: julia, dispatch

Since version 1.3 Julia allows [functor dispatch on abstract types](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/31916). Therefore, I was wondering whether it is possible to explicitly invoke the parent functor from a child object.

E.g. in the example below, is there any way to call `(x::Foo)()` through the `bar::Bar` object?

```
abstract type Foo end
(x::Foo)() = "Invoked Foo functor."

struct Bar <: Foo end
(x::Bar)() = "Invoked Bar functor."

bar = Bar()
@info "Calling bar functor directly."
bar() |> println
@info "Invoking parent functor."
# ??? - how to invoke parent functor (x::Foo)() (e.g. desired output "Invoked Foo functor")
invoke(bar,Tuple{Bar}, bar) |> println
```

Comment: any reason why you don't just want to define `function x(y :: Foo)... end`?

Comment: No, I could totally replace it with a function (as any  functionality that is offered by functors could be provided by a simple function instead). I was just wondering whether there is syntactic sugar to do this or whether I just have to stick to the workaround you suggested.

Comment: in Julia functions are much more idiomatic than defining a functor and messing with dispatch

Comment: This isn't immediately (or even non-immediately) possible as `invoke` is a builtin.  Now, what you might be able to do is ccall into Julia's internals at the proper point.  It'll just take some munging to essentially do [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f8067172557e4967714e92450f27d74dbf959760/src/gf.c#L2332-L2351) — and as a hack into an unofficial API it'll be prone to changes in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about using a `default` struct?

```
abstract type Foo end
(x::Foo)() = "Invoked Foo functor."

struct Bar <: Foo end
(x::Bar)() = "Invoked Bar functor."

struct DefaultFoo <: Foo end
#here we dont define an specialized method, DefaultFoo calls Foo

#an interface to define default methods: 
default(x::Type{Foo}) = DefaultFoo


function parent(x::T) where {T}
     y = default(supertype(T))
     return y()
end
```

finally, you can do this to call the default function:

```
bar = Bar()
foo = parent(bar)
foo()
```

this requires a definition of a `defaultFoo` type and a `default(x::Type{T})` for each supertype . you can automate this with the following macro:

```
macro create_default_functor(type)
    a = gensym(type)
    esc(quote
        struct $a <: $type end
        default(x::Type{$type})  = $a
    end)
end
```

using the macro, and your code:

```
abstract type Foo end
(x::Foo)() = "Invoked Foo functor."
@create_default_functor Foo
struct Bar <: Foo end
(x::Bar)() = "Invoked Bar functor."

function parent(x::T) where {T}
     y = default(supertype(T))
     return y()
end

#calling bar
bar = Bar()
bar()
#calling foo
foo = parent(bar)
foo()
```

I don't have the macro knowledge right now to call the macro directly on the abstract type definition, but is a start. 
The thing about abstract functors is that is a very new feature (1.3 is not out yet) and maybe this can be added on future versions of julia (something like `call_parent(Foo,args...)`, ) if you add a PR suggesting the feature.